# RSpec: how to expect ordered messages on two different objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

How to expect ordered messages on two different objects? Currently I have something like this:

```
call_order = ''

expect(double1).to receive(:msg1) { call_order += '1' }
expect(double2).to receive(:msg2) { call_order += '2' }

expect(call_order).to eq '12'
```

I know I can expect ordered messages on a single object using:

```
expect(double).to receive(:msg).ordered
expect(double).to receive(:other_msg).ordered
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/setting-constraints/message-order), rspec 3 allow it

```
collaborator_1 = double("Collaborator 1")
collaborator_2 = double("Collaborator 2")

expect(collaborator_1).to receive(:step_1).ordered
expect(collaborator_2).to receive(:step_2).ordered
expect(collaborator_1).to receive(:step_3).ordered

collaborator_1.step_1
collaborator_2.step_2
collaborator_1.step_3

#=> the examples should all pass
```